# How to access commandbindings in c# WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports

I'm using C# WPF application to display crystal reports and i want to call a function when crystal report viewer refresh button is clicked.

so in viewer properties i set command binding to refresh and application XAML looks like below

```
<Grid>
    <cr:CrystalReportsViewer Name="reportViewer">
        <cr:CrystalReportsViewer.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.Refresh"/>
        </cr:CrystalReportsViewer.CommandBindings>
    </cr:CrystalReportsViewer>
</Grid>
```

any idea how to capture this refresh event and call the command handler?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cr:CrystalReportViewer` is not a WPF control; therefore it has no `CommandBindings` property.

In order to be notified when the Refresh button was clicked, you could proceed as follows:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CRTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cr="clr-namespace:CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;assembly=CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <cr:CrystalReportViewer x:Name="reportViewer" ReportRefresh="OnReportRefresh"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load a sample report:
        ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Temp\test.rpt");
        reportViewer.ReportSource = doc;
    }

    private void OnReportRefresh(object source, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Refresh clicked!");
    }
}
```

Your code-behind must include

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

You need to add references to `WindowsFormIntegration`, `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms`, and `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` to your Visual Studio project.

Comment: since windows forms crystal report viewer doesn't render unicode font i use on reports, i use xmlns:cr="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"

Comment: I was not aware that SAP has released a WPF viewer; good to know! According to the documentation (http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet_api_2010_en.zip) there does not seem to be a "Refresh" event. Maybe you should ask SAP support.